# Why wouldn't the change event of a input type fire when I'm setting the value of that input type after the view is rendered?

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, view, render

In a backbone view, in its event hash I have added changed event of an input type which would fire a function and set values to some elements on the view. Now inside the view render, I have set value to the input type using underscore defer method, so that the value gets set after the view is appended to the DOM. This does set the value of the input type on the view, but it doesn't fire the changed event of it, which should set the values for other fields inside the view .

Any help is appreciated !

```
SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: 'example.html',
    events: {
        "change #InputElementId": "UpdateFields"
    },
    renderTemplate: function () {
        var view = this,
            model = view.options.selectedModel;

        podiumApp.fetchTemplate(view.template, function (tmpl) {
            view.$el.html(tmpl(model.toJSON()));
        });
    },
    render: function () {
        var view = this,
        view.renderTemplate();
        _.defer(view.loadInputValue);    `enter code here`   

        return view;
    },
    loadInputValue: function () {

            $('#InputElementId').val(model.get('InputRangeValue'));
    },
    UpdateFields: function(){`enter code here`
    // Some logic`enter code here`
      console.log('Changed event fired');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting value programmatically doesn't trigger `change` event, you have to trigger it yourself

`this.$('#InputElementId').val(model.get('InputRangeValue')).trigger('change');`

---

```js
  SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
      template: 'example.html',
      events: {
        'change #InputElementId': 'updateFields'
      },
      initialize: function() {
        this.model = this.options.selectedModel;
      },
      renderTemplate: function() {
        podiumApp.fetchTemplate(this.template, function(tmpl) {
          this.$el.html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));
        }.bind(this));
      },
      render: function() {
        this.renderTemplate();
        _.defer(this.loadInputValue.bind(this));
        return this;
      },
      loadInputValue: function() {
        var value = this.model.get('InputRangeValue');
        this.$('#InputElementId').val(value).trigger('change');
      },
      UpdateFields: function() {
        // Some logic
        console.log('Changed event fired');
      });
```